# I am having issues with this constructor and getting a compiler error

Tags: java, constructor

It's pretty simple program:

Create a method for the calculate class that will take in two numbers and add them together (use class variables for this!). For an extra challenge, create more than one class method for this: one class method to take in the numbers and another to do the calculation. 
Create a method to display the results of the calculation by displaying the contents of a class variable that holds the calculation results. 
Create a main method that will declare an object of the calculate class and use all of the methods of that class.

This is what i've come up with but it won't let me pass any values to the calculator class because I don't have constructors yet I do have constructor method in getNum. Please help

```
public class MainCalc {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   calculator calcOne = new calculator();
   System.out.println("calcOne equals: " + calcOne.calculate());
}

class calculator
{
   private int num1;
   private int num2;
   public int answer;

   public void getNum(int i, int j) 
   {
   num1 = i;
   num2 = j;
   }

public int calculate()
{
 answer = num1 + num2;

 return answer;
}
}

}
```

Comment: Semantic issue. You should not be setting values in a function named `get*`

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
public void getNum(int i, int j) 
   {
```

to be

```
public calculator(int i, int j) 
{
```

A constructor has no return type and is otherwise essentially a function with the same name as the class, to keep it simple. Please look at [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for more information.

And construct the calculator with 2 values like so.

```
new calculator(1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
class calculator
```

to

```
static class calculator
```

because you are referencing it within the `static` context of your `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class MainCalc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Calculator calcOne = new Calculator();
    System.out.println("calcOne equals: " + calcOne.addTwoNumbers(10, 25));
}

static class Calculator {
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private int answer;

    public int addTwoNumbers(int i, int j) {
        num1 = i;
        num2 = j;
        calculate(num1, num2);
        return answer;
    }

    private void calculate(int i, int j) {
        answer = i + j;

    }
}
}
```

The addTwoNumbers method takes in two integers as paremeters, sets the class variables num1 & num2 equal to them.  Then calls the calculate method which takes those two variables as inputs, performs the calculation & sets the answer variable equal to it.  Then the addTwoNumbers method returns answer.  This should meet your requirement that a separate method perform the calculation.